# Real-Time Data-Binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a table that displays a list of uploaded files. If I uploaded a file it needs to be reflected in the table. This is already happening — not, however, in real-time. I need to refresh the page to reflect the data that I need.

I tried refreshing the div in jquery but it is not working:

```html
<div class="mjs-cell">
            <div id="stipsData" data-bind="template:{name: 'rehash-customertab-stips-section', data: stipsViewModel}">
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="mjs-row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Stip Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
                <tr class="stips-row">
                    <td class="hidden stips-id" data-bind="text: StipulationTypeId"></td>
                    <td class="stips-text">
                        <a data-bind="text: StipulationType"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="stips-status">
                        <span data-bind="text: Status"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="stips-uploaded-file" data-bind="text: FileName"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the code that I use for binding:

```js
  stipsViewModel = ko.computed(function () {
            DealApiControllers.GetStipulations(dealId,
                (response) => {
                    this.stipsViewModel = response.DealStipulationsDTOs;
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }, this);
```

For example the table shows Doc1, Doc2. If I upload Doc3 it should be reflected in the list.

Comment: Could you post the code responsible for setting `$data` in your viewModel?

Comment: I updated the question caseyWebb